# Error when reading Wikipedia’s data with R and readr

Tags: r

I am new for R programming. I am using R 3.4.2 in mac OS X El Capitan V10.11.6.

When I tried to read data from below url, I got errors.

Data Source Link:
https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2017/2017-10/pageviews-20171001-010000.gz

The file contains four fields:Language, Wikipedia Page Title, Number of requests the page received this hour, Total size in bytes of the content returned. It's csv file separated by space without header line.

I tried to read table with below code:

```
df <- read.table("https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2017/2017-10/pageviews-20171001-010000.gz", sep = " ", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

The error I got is

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
>     line 1 did not have 2 elements
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In read.table("https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2017/2017-10/pageviews-20171001-010000.gz",  :
>     line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls

Also I tried to use readr package, still failed. The code I used is below

```
df <- read_delim("https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2017/2017-10/pageviews-20171001-010000.gz", delim = " ", col_names = FALSE)
```

BTW, when I read this data with spark scala, there is no issue.

Comment: adding output of `devtools::session_info()` may help triage root cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)

gzfile("pageviews-20171001-010000.gz") %>% 
  readLines(skipNul=TRUE) %>% 
  stri_split_fixed(" ", simplify=TRUE) %>% 
  as_data_frame() -> xmat

xmat

## # A tibble: 4,598,475 x 4
##       V1                                V2    V3    V4
##    <chr>                             <chr> <chr> <chr>
##  1    aa                 Category:Articles     1     0
##  2    aa                  Category:User_aa     1     0
##  3    aa        File:Wikipedia-logo-en.png     2     0
##  4    aa                         Main_Page    35     0
##  5    aa               Special:ActiveUsers     6     0
##  6    aa Special:Contributions/Lars~aawiki     1     0
##  7    aa    Special:Contributions/PipepBot     1     0
##  8    aa                 Special:ListFiles     3     0
##  9    aa                 Special:ListUsers     3     0
## 10    aa                Special:Statistics    10     0
## # ... with 4,598,465 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks, @hrbrmstr. Just wonder why read.table and read_delim did not work. Can you help?

Comment: b/c there are, indeed, embedded nulls and the underlying scala/java for spark is likely being more forgiving. `read_delim("pageviews-20171001-010000.gz", delim=" ", col_names=FALSE, locale=locale(encoding="UTF-8"))` also works

Comment: I tried add locale with read_delim. Still I got 4,421,548 rows rather than 4,598,475

Answer (score 0):

Works in my case. Could it be system/package-version dependent?

```
library(readr)

df <- read_delim("https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2017/2017-10/pageviews-20171001-010000.gz", 
                 delim = " ", col_names = FALSE)
df
# A tibble: 4,421,548 x 4
##X1                                X2    X3    X4
##<chr>                             <chr> <int> <int>
##1    aa                 Category:Articles     1     0
##2    aa                  Category:User_aa     1     0
##3    aa        File:Wikipedia-logo-en.png     2     0
##4    aa                         Main_Page    35     0
##5    aa               Special:ActiveUsers     6     0
##6    aa Special:Contributions/Lars~aawiki     1     0
##7    aa    Special:Contributions/PipepBot     1     0
##8    aa                 Special:ListFiles     3     0
##9    aa                 Special:ListUsers     3     0
##10    aa                Special:Statistics    10     0
# ... with 4,421,538 more rows
sessionInfo()
##R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
##Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
##Running under: Ubuntu 17.10
##
##Matrix products: default
##BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
##LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so
##
##locale:
##[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
##[3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
##[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
##[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
##[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
##[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
##
##attached base packages:
##[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: it's def behaving differently on my macOS. tosses tons of warnings even ith `read_delim("pageviews-20171001-010000.gz", delim=" ", col_names=FALSE, locale=locale(encoding="UTF-8"))`

Comment: Yes, there are also warnings under the Ubuntu as well.

Comment: With this, you got 4,421,548 results, but actually it should be 4,598,475.